# How to set default shortcut to change language in Win 10?

Tags: windows-10

Built-in binding allows me only to rebind it to the following values:

- Alt+Shift
- Ctrl+Shift

etc.

How to use custom keybinding, like Win+Alt+Space?

Comment: I think that there is no such settings on windows, hope some software could help you. http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/10/featured/free-keyboard-shortcut-software-windows-10.html

Comment: Seems like none of them are working :(